# How to get only one specific row data from nested relationship in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, inertiajs

I have 3 models connected by simple one-to-many relationships:
One Client(has many) Points,
One Point (has many) order_powers. The order_powers table has value and date_from columns. date_from is the date from which the value of of the ordered power is valid.

In Client model:

```
  public function points() {
        return $this->hasMany(Point::class);
    }
    
    public function order_powers() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(OrderPower::class, Point::class);
    }
```

In Point model:

```
 public function clients() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}

public function order_powers() {
    return $this->hasMany(OrderPower::class);
}
```

In OrderPower model:

```
public function order_powers() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Point::class);
}
```

I want to display on single page:

1. data of a single Client
2. data of Points belonging to this Client
3. Ordered power for each of the Client's Points. Only one value of Object with the most recent "date from" should be displayed.

My rendering ClientController with Inertia and Vue looks like this and actually points 1 and 2 are DONE, point 3 is a problem for me. Currently, the controller displays all ordered powers of a given Point. I don't know how to display only one value of column 'value' depending on the date_from column?

```
return Inertia::render('Clientshow', [
          'client' => [
            'id' => $client->id,
            'name' => $client->name,
            'street' => $client->street,
            'city' => $client->city,
            'points' => $client->points()->with(['order_powers'=>function ($q)
            {
                $q->orderBy('date_from','desc');
            }
            ])->get(),         
          ],
        ]);
```

Example:

- one Client has two Points
- each Point has two order_powers
- Vue shows all two values for each of the points, I want just one (first(), take(1) shows only one order_power value for ALL Points.

My Vue component:

```
>client:Reactive
   id:33
   name:"ClientName"
   street:"StreetName"
   city:"CityName"
  >points:Array[2]
   >0:Object
     client_id:33
     created_at:"2022-10-13T15:31:37.000000Z"
     id:65
     >order_powers:Array[2] <- I want display only one value of column "value" of one Object
      >0:Object
      >1:Object
     pp_type:"xxxx"
     updated_at:"2022-10-13T15:31:37.000000Z"
   >1:Object
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understant your problem, but i think that if you want to select just the value of column value in model Point you can use:

```
'points' => $client->points()->with(['order_powers:id,value'=>function ($q) ...
```

Comment: I am just learning, so my description is definitely confusing;) it will be easiest for me to explain this way:
https://ibb.co/m45t5JT